# Win flex-bison compiling produces invalid character errors

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I managed to install win flex-bison(version 2.5.16) on Windows 10. I copied a sample lexer program from one of the tutorials i found and tried to compile it with the following instruction:

```
win_flex -o lexer.cpp lexer.l
```

The file lexer.l is :

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>

#define YY_DECL int yylex()

#include "calc.tab.h"

%}

%%

[ \t]   ; // ignore all whitespace
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+  {yylval.fval = atof(yytext); return T_FLOAT;}
[0-9]+      {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return T_INT;}
\n      {return T_NEWLINE;}
"+"     {return T_PLUS;}
"-"     {return T_MINUS;}
"*"     {return T_MULTIPLY;}
"/"     {return T_DIVIDE;}
"("     {return T_LEFT;}
")"     {return T_RIGHT;}
"exit"      {return T_QUIT;}
"quit"      {return T_QUIT;}

%%
```

When i compile it reports a bunch of similar errors on every line of the file, for example:

```
lexer.l:19: bad character:
lexer.l:19: bad character: }
lexer.l:19: bad character:
lexer.l:19: bad character:
lexer.l:19: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character: "
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character: *
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character: "
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character: {
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: unknown error processing section 1
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: unknown error processing section 1
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: unknown error processing section 1
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: unknown error processing section 1
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: unknown error processing section 1
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: unknown error processing section 1
lexer.l:20: bad character:
lexer.l:20: bad character:
```

I will add that this happens on an older version of win_flex as well as with every other sample lexer file i tried. One of the first errors in the long output reports this:

```
lexer.l:1: bad character:  
lexer.l:1: bad character: ■
lexer.l:1: bad character: %
```

I have no idea where it's taking these characters from. A similar thing is happening with win_bison when i compile the parser.y file but there are only a few error messages (very similar to the ones above):

```
Process "parser.y" bison file
1>  parser.y:1.1-2: error: invalid characters: ' ■'
1>    ■%     ^^
1>  parser.y:1.3: error: invalid character: '%'
1>    ■%       ^
1>  parser.y:1.4: error: invalid character: '\0'
1>    ■%        ^
1>  parser.y:1.4-15.2: error: syntax error, unexpected {...}
1>    ■%        ^^^^^^
```

Seems as if win_flex rejects every single character in any input i provide it.
So the question is am i missing sth obvious or should i stop wasting time and use Jflex and Cup?

EDIT: Someone somewhere mentioned it could be a problem with the encoding of the file. I checked and its UTF-8. I don't know what it should be and could it cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex and bison input files should be ASCII, not UTF-8. Make sure there are no characters in the file which are not in the basic ASCII set. This includes:

- The BOM at the beginning of the file, if there is one (and from the bison errors, I'd say there definitely is).
- Non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work now (even though i had to retype the file to check).